# Not able to frame correct JSON String

Tags: json, gson

I am learning JSON and using **gson** to frame json string.
Here it is what i need.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "interface_type": "web",
  "request_type": "1",
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test",
  "sender_id": "test",
  "doctor_advice": false,
  "type": "test",
  "bulk": "test",
  "msg": "test",
  "recipients": [
    919845098450,
    919845098451
  ]
}
```

But i am getting like this.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "interface_type": "web",
  "request_type": "1",
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test",
  "sender_id": "test",
  "doctor_advice": false,
  "type": "test",
  "bulk": "test",
  "msg": "test",
  "recepients": [
    "9845098450",
    "9845098451",
    {}
  ]
}
```

Please let me know how to make the request as above mentioned.

Here is the code

```
import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
public class gsonWriter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JsonObject request = new JsonObject();
        request.addProperty("version", "1.0");
        request.addProperty("interface_type", "web");
        request.addProperty("request_type", "1");
        request.addProperty("username", "test");
        request.addProperty("password", "test");
        request.addProperty("sender_id", "test");
        request.addProperty("doctor_advice", false);
        request.addProperty("type", "test");
        request.addProperty("bulk", "test");
        request.addProperty("msg", "test");
        JsonArray recepients = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject recepientList = new JsonObject();
        recepients.add(new JsonPrimitive("9845098450"));
        recepients.add(new JsonPrimitive("9845098451"));
        recepients.add(recepientList);
        request.add("recepients", recepients);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls()
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
                .create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(request));
    }
}
```

and i don't want to use `java-pojo` for the same. Need plain string to pass it through URL.
Your help is much appreciated.

Also please suggest me an open source Json binder better than gson could be `Jackson`,`Json`, `Genson` or if any other which could help me to develop fully fledged application in which application continuously hit to restful services and receives the response from the same :).

Comment: Did you look up what the 'request.addProperty()' method does?

Comment: @LisaMM request.addProperty() is working correctly as expected. i edited the question please check now. problem is with array creation. I don't need key for that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 differences in this fragment:

```
"recepients": [
  "9845098450",
  "9845098451",
  {}
]
```

1. Recipients must be numbers, not strings.
2. There shouldn't be that `{}` empty object.

Correct code:

```
JsonObject request = new JsonObject();
request.addProperty("version", "1.0");
request.addProperty("interface_type", "web");
request.addProperty("request_type", "1");
request.addProperty("username", "test");
request.addProperty("password", "test");
request.addProperty("sender_id", "test");
request.addProperty("doctor_advice", false);
request.addProperty("type", "test");
request.addProperty("bulk", "test");
request.addProperty("msg", "test");

JsonArray recepients = new JsonArray();
recepients.add(new JsonPrimitive(9845098450L));
recepients.add(new JsonPrimitive(9845098451L));
request.add("recepients", recepients);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .serializeNulls()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
        .create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(request));
```

To pass recipients as a numbers, you need to pass a number in the JsonPrimitive constructor. Your values are too large for `int` type, so we need to make them `long` by adding suffix `L`.

To avoid empty `{}` object, just remove `recepientList` variable, it's not needed at all.

Comment: thanks it's working. I need to choose a better json binder. please can you help in that.

Comment: I used gson without problems in many projects and definitely can recommend it. Fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of `recipientsList` to the `recipients JSonArray` should not be necessary. Delete those lines and you will get the same output as you requested. Now you are adding an empty `JSonObject`, shown by the `{}` .